# UI Automator with custom keyboard. Find exact keyboard button and click it

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to write UI automation tests for the custom soft keyboard using UI Automator and\or Espresso. Tried different ways but I can't find a proper solution to "find the exact button on the opened keyboard and click it".

Problems:

1. UIAtomator's `UiDevice.findObject(By.text("Q")).click()` doesn't find Q button on keyboard.
2. Espresso's `onView(withText("Q")).perform(click())` doesn't find the button either.

For now, it looks like the only way to click button is to measure XY coordinates based on screen height and keyboard height. But this solution is ugly and not persistent.

`typeText("text")`and `uiObject.text = "text"` don't work since it bypasses keyboard input.

Was anyone working with custom keyboards? Please help.

Comment: From what I've found out, the IME is running in it's own process started by the system. You won't have access to it's view-hierarchy ever if you're running your own tests...

Comment: You might actually be best off starting some local tcp server which your test can connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building a custom soft keyboard then I expect you're using a `KeyboardView`. `KeyboardView` draws the keys using a canvas therefore it is not possible to get the resource ids of the keys... so no chance to find them through the `UiDevice`'s `findObject` method.

Considering the `KeyboardView` class is deprecated since API 29, a possible solution will be to reimplement your own `KeyboardView` (as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html)) and use `AccessibilityNodeInfo` class to build virtual elements (one for each key) that will be included into the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
   val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
    device.pressEnter()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in my opinion would be to create your own TCP server to solve this issue. Please refer to this link to find out how: https://ops.tips/blog/a-tcp-server-in-c/